# Problems adding Jenkins-Server to Jira

Tags: plugins, integration, jenkins, jira

I would like to configure the Hudson/Jenkins-Plugin for Jira to access the Jenkins-Server via Jira.

```
Jenkins-Server-Version     : Jenkins ver. 1.446
Jira-Version               : v4.4.4#664-r167664
Jira Hudson Plugin Version : 4.3.0
```

I set the

```
Host URL: "http://<IP of the Server>:8080/jenkins/"
```

and the result is

```
Failed to check if the API v2 plugin is installed on specified server. 
Please verify that the plugin is installed and that the JIRA server can 
access the Hudson/Jenkins Server.
```

I found the hint "Don't forget to install the Hudson/Jenkins plugin!". So I installed the

```
Jenkins JIRA plugin
This plugin integrates Jenkins to Atlassian JIRA.
1.29
```

but no effect, same error-message while adding Jenkins-Server to Plugin-Configuration in Jira.

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins JIRA plugin is not the one you need to install. Follow the instructions in the [Installation Guide](http://docs.marvelution.com/display/MARVJIRAHUDSON/Installation+Guide).

Note the link to the [JIRA Hudson Integration Repository](http://docs.marvelution.com/display/REPO/JIRA+Hudson+Integration+Repository+Directory), where you get the right plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the API V2 plugin on hudson/jenkins.
there is the address,you can download it.

> http://docs.marvelution.com/display/REPO/JIRA+Hudson+Integration

in total,you should install jira plugin and API v2 plugin on hudson/jenkins,and install JIRA hudson plugin on jira.

Comment: Having the same issue but the links are not longer valid.